# Exception when defining the properties of a class

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a database application in C# using VS. I have a class called Crew and has its own fields such name, date of birth ... etc. I want the user to specify some of the fields, while others to be automatically calculated/ figured out by the application itself. Such as age to be calculated from the date of birth. Here is how I am doing this:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
public DateTime DOB
{
    set { }
    get { return DOB.Date; }
}
public int Age
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Year) - Convert.ToInt32(DOB.Year); }
}
```

While debugging, I fill out the fields for a person and hit the create button to save to the database, but an exception arises saying the following:

> System.StackOverflowException occurred
>   HResult=0x800703E9 Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

Answer (score 2):

In the getter for `DOB`, you reference `DOB`.  So then it has to access the getter for `DOB`, which references `DOB`.  So it has to access `DOB`....

A property cannot access itself when trying to get it's value, or you'll enter an infinite loop and get a SO exception.  You can get around this by having a `private` backing field that stores the value, then access that in the property getter:

```
private DateTime _dob;

public DateTime DOB
{
    get { return _dob; }
    set { _dob= value; }
}
```

Comment: I have to store the value from outside the class since the property is going to be inputted by the user.

Comment: Based on OP's question, it should be `get { return _dob.Date; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, but how can I assign _dob if it is private?

Comment: @MahmoudHamad, You don't (unless you want to set it in a constructor). You set the value of the property `DOB` which in turn set s the value of the backing field